What is wrong with my logic in this dice and coin problem?
I was solving this problem:

There is a die and a coin. The dice is rolled and the coin is flipped according to the number the die is rolled. If the die is rolled only once, what is the probability of 4 successive heads?

My methodology:
Case 1: Die rolls $4$
P(4Heads) = $\frac{1}{6}.\frac{1}
{2}\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}
{2}\frac{1}
{2}=\frac{1}{6}.\frac{1}
{2^4}$
Case 2: Die rolls $5$
P(4Heads) = $5.\frac{1}{6}.\frac{1}
{2}\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}
{2}\frac{1}
{2}\frac{1}
{2}=5.\frac{1}{6}.\frac{1}
{2^5}$
{Multiplied by $5$ because there are $\frac{5!}{4!}$ different arrangements possible for heads in $5$ coin throws}
Case 3: Die rolls $6$
P(4Heads) = $5.\frac{1}{6}.\frac{1}
{2}\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}
{2}\frac{1}
{2}\frac{1}
{2}\frac{1}
{2}=15.\frac{1}{6}.\frac{1}
{2^6}$
{Multiplied by $15$ because there are $\frac{6!}{4!.2!}$ different arrangements possible for heads in $6$ coin throws}
Net probability = $\frac{1}{6.2^4}.\frac{29}{4}$
However the answer in the book is different from my answer. So, please help me understand if there is some lapse in my logic.
Edit:
The answer in my book is given as $\frac{1}{16}$ which I'm unable to get.
I also found this Quora post which arrived at the same answer but I couldn't understand its methodology

It's asking for the probability of $4$ successive heads, not $4$ heads total.

Outcomes such as $HHHTH$ and $HTHHTH$ are not permissible because they do not have four successive heads, yet they are included in your computation.
To get $4$ successive heads, there are only $3$ ways to do it in $5$ coin tosses:  $HHHHT$, $THHHH$, $HHHHH$.  There can't be any tails in between the heads, so any tail must be at the end.
How many arrangements are possible for $6$ coin tosses?  Try enumerating them like I showed for $5$ coin tosses.  Then recompute your probability.

Thank you. I did so and the answer I'm getting is $\frac{1}{6.2^4}.\frac{16}{4}$ = $\frac{1}{24}$ when I multiplied the Case 3 with 6 instead of 15 and added the probabilities. But the answer in the book is given as $\frac{1}{16}$. Is there another mistake that I have made or is the answer in the book wrong?

There are $8$ ways to get (at least) $4$ successive heads in $6$ coin tosses, so the probability that I get is $3/64$.

Can you please tell which cases I'm missing as for me I had 3 for 4 heads, 2 for 5 heads and 1 for 6 heads ?

I have also added link to a quora post which arrived at the same answer as the one in my problem book but the methodology of which I couldn't understand.

@Madly_Maths  I get $HHHHHH$, $HHHHHT$, $HHHHTH$, $HHHHTT$, $HTHHHH$, $THHHHH$, $THHHHT$, $TTHHHH$.

Yeah, I commented on one of the Quora answers. They seem to assume that overlapping sequences are independent, which by and large they are not. Or mutually exclusive (which they also aren't). It's not exactly clear what they're assuming.

@Madly_Maths I browsed the Quora posts and to be perfectly honest, I can relate to your confusion.  Regardless, under the assumptions that the die and coin are fair and their outcomes are independent, and that the question is asking for at least four successive heads, then the answer is $3/64$.  If we require exactly four successive heads and not more, then the answer is smaller than $3/64$; since $1/16 > 3/64$, there is an error in the Quora post's reasoning or a difference in assumptions.

To strengthen @heropup's point, I solved the problem independently and also got $3/64$ as answer.

Thank you very much everyone for helping me. I too think that this logic is sound and the one in the quora post and my book just made some wrong assumptions.
